# Problemas al querer enviar formulario en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web, webforms, wordpress-plugin

Mi problema es el siguiente estoy tratando de incluir un formulario de consultas en `wordpress`, el tema es que por ninguna razon logro poder hacerlo andar. He configurado los servicios `smtp` utilizando diferentes `plugins` pero no obtuve exito. Probe realizar una prueba con `Check Email` devuelve como respuesta que el email sale al destinatario (en mi caso una casilla de gmail) pero a mi bandeja de entrada nunca llega. Adjunto una imagen de mi configuracion `smtp`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy viendo en la imagen que la configuración no está correcta te adjunto los datos correctamente.

```
**User SMTP**: Yes
**SMTP Source:** SSL
**SMTP Auth:** Yes
**Port:** 465
**Host:** smtp.gmail.com
**Username:** tucorreo@gmail.com
**Password:** Tú contraseña
**From Email: ** El email al que el cliente podrá responder.
**From Name: ** El nombre del correo enviado.
```

Las siguientes opciones las dejas como las tienes.

Comment: Ahi subi una imagen con las correcciones que me hiciste pero aun asi sigo sin poder enviar un correo de prueba.

Comment: Intenta hablar con tu proveedor del hosting, por que igual el problema viene de ellos y no de tu configuración.